# Выравнивание текста в span

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как выровнять текст внутри элемента span?
Т.е. по вертикали выравнивает, а по горизонтали нет.

```
   <html>
      <body>
        <span style="background-color: red;
                     color: white;
                     padding: 6px;
                     position: absolute;
                 text-align: center;
                     width: 195px;
                     height: 120px;
             top: 0;
                     left: 0;
                     bottom: 0;
             right: 0;
                     margin: auto;">ВНИМАНИЕ!</span>
      </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте задать `line-height: 120px;` и убрать `padding: 6px;`

Comment: Спасибо. А что означает line-height? Прочитал, что устанавливает интерлиньяж, но не понимаю, что это.

Comment: Это междустрочный интервал. Я так часто выравниваю текст внутри блоков, если он написан в одну строку. У вас высота красного блока равна 120px, и мы установили такой же интерлиньяж. Т.е. текст думает, что его интервал такой же, как и наш блок, соответственно, оказывается по центру.

Answer (score 0):

Это, конечно, тоже хороший вариант, возьму на заметку. А можно еще сделать и так:

```
.class{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

И теперь можете какой угодно текст вставить, центрирование будет постоянно в центре)